# Formula to find square root of a Natural number using only addition and subtraction.

Tags: arithmetic, radicals, natural-numbers

I searched over the internet but i didn't find any relevant answer relating to this problem. 
So, is it possible to create a formula to get square root of a natural number using only addition and subtraction operators?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to count?

Comment: hmm,no multiplication ? then what square and what is square root then?